# The usage of NSNotificationCenter in the relationship of parent and children

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications

Here is the case:
I get a class A and A registers notification when app comes from background to foreground.
I get another class B which is inherited from class A.

So, if I implement the selector on both class A and class B.
Which selector will get called event happens?
How if I implement the selector on class B only?
Is it something just like the parent-children?

Comment: Did you try it? What happens? It's best to try your code before posting a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so lets say that you register for notifications in the `viewDidLoad` method (I'm assuming you're using `UIViewController`) in Class A; and deregistering for notifications in the `viewWillDisappear:` method. Then as long as you call `super` in your subclass' (Class B) equivalent methods then your class will receive these notifications.

In order to respond to these notifications you create a method, defined in the .h file of the superclass (Class A) called `didEnterForeground` and you set this as the selector to be called when your superclass receives the notification. All you have to do is implement `didEnterForeground` in your subclass (Class B) in order to respond to notifications.

As an example I have a custom class of `UIViewController` which defines certain behaviours that I want to be universal to the App. My superclass `RHViewController` detects certain touches (e.g. three fingers held down for more than 1 second) and calls a selector `performQuickPrint`. The subclasses of `RHViewController` then implement `performQuickPrint` in order to respond to the user holding down 3 fingers.

In order to implement code on only the subclasses of `RHViewController` i just never call `super`.

This is a bit like if you override `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and don't call `[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];` you can lose a lot of functionality.

Hope this helps.